# Netty - Unit testing idle state of handlers using IdleStateHandler

Tags: java, netty

I'm attempting to test my own handlers, which listen to `io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateEvent` from `io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler`. I'm don't see anyone else having this issue, but when I sleep in my code to trigger the idle events, the idle events are not triggering. I believe that's due to the embedded channel running on the same thread? Below is an example test.

```java
@Test
public void userEventTriggered_IdleStateEvent() throws Exception {
    // given
    IdleStateHandler idleStateHandler = new IdleStateHandler(
            1L,0L,0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(idleStateHandler, myHandler);

    // when
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

    // then
    assertFalse(channel.isActive());

    channel.finish();
}
```

I have noticed in the [unit tests for IdleStateHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/handler/src/test/java/io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandlerTest.java) that a testable handler has been created which makes use of [package-scoped methods](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.java#L335-L347) to test the handler.

Is there any way to test the idle events from outside the package? I need to ensure coverage for these events. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `channel.runPendingTasks()` after sleeping. This should execute the scheduled tasks that are now ready.

Comment: Perfect! That worked exactly how I was expecting. Also, if someone else comes to this question, the events are triggered in order, so if you want to trigger write, read, all idle states in that order, you can. Thanks for your help, Norman!